# Reacr router modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, popup

Скажите как я могу отобразить модальное окно **/login** над предыдущим роутом(например **/home**).

**Что бы за модальным окном просматривалась страница?**

Comment: может просто компоненту из роута login вставить в модальное окно?

Comment: Можно показывать модалку без использования роутера. Управляйте  отображением модалки состоянием, в зависимости от его изменения рисуйте компонент модального окна а в нем ваш логин